# Manage reports, when our database is Cassandra ...Spark or Solr...or BOTH?

Tags: hadoop, solr, apache-spark, cassandra, apache-hive

My db is **Cassandra** (datastax enterprise => linux). Since it doesn't support group-by, aggregate and etc. for reporting, according to its fundamentals, it's not a good decision to use Cassandra, downright. I googled about this deficit and found some results as [this](http://www.slideshare.net/patrickmcfadin/a-cassandra-solr-spark-love-triangle-using-datastax-enterprise-50051760), and [this](http://www.slideshare.net/planetcassandra/an-introduction-to-distributed-search-with-cassandra-and-solr) and also [this one](http://www.slideshare.net/MarkedUpAnalytics/real-time-analytics-with-cassandra-hive-and-solr).

But I really became confused! **Hive** uses additional tables, individually. **Solr** is better for full-text searching and like that. And **Spark**...it's useful for analysis, but, I didn't understand if it uses Hadoop eventually, or not.

I will have many reports, which needs indexing and grouping, at least. But I don't want to use additional tables which will impose overhead. And also, I'm .Net (and not Java) developer, and my application is besed on **.Net Framework**, too.

Answer (score 1):

I am not exactly sure what your question is here and your confusion is understandable as with Cassandra and DSE there is a lot going on.

- You are correct in stating that Cassandra does not support any aggregations or group by functionality that you would want to use for reporting.
- Solr (DSE Search) is used for ad-hoc and full text searching of the data stored in Cassandra.  This only works on a single table at a time.
- Spark (DSE Analytics) provides analytics capabilities such as Map-Reduce as well as the ability to filter and join tables.  This is not done in real-time though as the processing and shuffling of data can be expensive depending on the data load.
- Spark does not use Hadoop.  It performs many of the same jobs but is more efficient in many scenarios as it allows for in-memory distributed processing on the data.

Since you are using DataStax Enterprise the advantage is that you have built in connectors to both Solr (DSE Search) to provide ad-hoc queries and Spark (DSE Analytics) to provide analytics on your data.

Since I don't know your exact reporting requirements it is difficult to give you a specific recommendation.  If you can provide some additional details about what sort of reporting (scheduled versus ad-hoc etc.) you will be running I may be able to help you more.

Comment: The app. has many users. It will have Scheduled and ad-hoc reporting, both. It should make some reports periodically: daily, per month, every four months, and per year, for the admin And also,  should be able to support ad-hoc reporting request, for users.